# How to share custom stickers from my app to telegram app through its APIs with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, telegram, swift5

I am looking for a clean way to share my custom stickers from my application using telegram APIs.
I have been searching telegram documentation about how to send custom stickers with the proper way to be read through telegram.
I found here how to create the sticker set -> https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#stickerset,
and here how to make the stickers itself -> https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#stickerset

This is my code for preparing the stickerSet and stickers

```
func handleStickersForTelegram(completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    
    StickerPackManager.queue.async {
        var json: [String: Any] = [:]
        
        
        json["name"] = self.name
        json["title"] = self.publisher
        json["contains_masks"] = false
        if self.animated == true {
            json["is_animated"] = true
        }
        var stickersArray: [[String: Any]] = []
        
        
        for sticker in 1...self.stickers.count {
            
            var stickerDict: [String: Any] = [:]
            print("stickerTest", self.stickers.count )
            stickerDict["file_id"] = "\(StickerBaseURL)/\(self.identifier)/\(sticker).webp"
            stickerDict["set_name"] = self.name
            stickerDict["file_unique_id"] = "\(self.identifier)/\(sticker).webp"
            stickerDict["width"] = 96
            stickerDict["height"] = 96
            
            if self.animated == true {
                stickerDict["is_animated"] = true
                
            }
            stickersArray.append(stickerDict)
        }
        
        json["stickers"] = stickersArray
        
        let result = Interoperability.sendToTelegram(json: json)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completionHandler(result)
        }
    }
}
```

And after calling `Interoperability.sendToTelegram(json:json)`I have tried to make the function the way I did for sharing custom stickers to Whatsapp but didn't find the proper information to do that here is my function for whatsapp sharing.

```
struct Interoperability {
    private static let DefaultBundleIdentifier: String = "MyBundleIdentifier"
    private static let PasteboardExpirationSeconds: TimeInterval = 60
    private static let PasteboardStickerPackDataType: String = "net.whatsapp.third-party.sticker-pack"
    private static let WhatsAppURL: URL = URL(string: "whatsapp://stickerPack")!
    
    static func send(json: [String: Any]) -> Bool {
        if let bundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
            if bundleIdentifier.contains(DefaultBundleIdentifier) {
                fatalError("Your bundle identifier must not include the default one.");
            }
        }
        
        let pasteboard: UIPasteboard = UIPasteboard.general
        
        var jsonWithAppStoreLink: [String: Any] = json
        jsonWithAppStoreLink["ios_app_store_link"] = iOSAppStoreLink
        jsonWithAppStoreLink["android_play_store_link"] = AndroidStoreLink
        
        guard let dataToSend = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonWithAppStoreLink, options: []) else {
            return false
        }
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            pasteboard.setItems([[PasteboardStickerPackDataType: dataToSend]], options: [UIPasteboard.OptionsKey.localOnly: true, UIPasteboard.OptionsKey.expirationDate: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: PasteboardExpirationSeconds)])
        } else {
            pasteboard.addItems([[PasteboardStickerPackDataType: dataToSend]])
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "whatsapp://")!) {
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(WhatsAppURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                } else {
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(WhatsAppURL)
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

This my approach for making the same for telegram but didn't work!
I have added to my struct above

```
struct Interoperability {
    private static let stickerSetDataType: String = "stickers.createStickerSet"
    private static let testTelegram: URL = URL(string: "tg://StickerSet")!
    
    static func sendToTelegram(json: [String: Any]) -> Bool {
        
        if let bundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
            if bundleIdentifier.contains(DefaultBundleIdentifier) {
                fatalError("Your bundle identifier must not include the default one.");
            }
        }
        
        let pasteboard: UIPasteboard = UIPasteboard.general
        guard let dataToSend = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: []) else {
            return false
        }
        
        pasteboard.addItems([[stickerSetDataType: dataToSend]])
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "tg://")!) {
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(testTelegramURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                } else {
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(testTelegramURL)
                }
            }
        }
        
        return true
    }
}
```

It opens the telegram but nothing happens no stickers there is no sign that telegram read my stickers.
I don't know if I saved the stickers data in `UIPasteboard` with a wrong way or these info are wrong.

```
   private static let stickerSetDataType: String = "stickers.createStickerSet"
   private static let testTelegram: URL = URL(string: "tg://StickerSet")!
```

Answer (score 0):

Telegram app not work like whatsapp. you need to add your sticker package on telegram by following this link

https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-make-telegram-stickers/

Once you add your package on telegram then you can use your package name to add sticker package on telegram by using following code

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://telegram.me/addstickers/ClassicAlice") {
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url)
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }     
}
```